# Aerospike asbackup command generates invalid namespace error

Tags: aerospike

To backup data from test namespace in Aerospike database to current directory, the following asbackup command generates an invalid namespace error.

There is the test namespace and employee set in it with few records. I can read and write the records using golang driver. Is there any configuration required for asbackup?

```
asbackup --host 172.28.128.3:3000 --namespace test  --directory .
```

Error is:

```
2020-02-11 16:48:32 UTC [INF] [88270] Starting 100% backup of 172.28.128.3:3000 
(namespace: test, set: [all], bins: [all], after: [none], before: [none]) to .
2020-02-11 16:48:32 UTC [INF] [88270] [src/main/aerospike/as_cluster.c:124] 
[as_cluster_add_nodes_copy] Add node BB949C170270008 172.28.128.3:3000
2020-02-11 16:48:32 UTC [INF] [88270] Processing 1 node(s)
2020-02-11 16:48:32 UTC [INF] [88270] Node ID Objects Replication    
2020-02-11 16:48:32 UTC [ERR] [88270] Invalid namespace test
2020-02-11 16:48:32 UTC [ERR] [88270] Error while counting cluster objects
```

Using MacOs 10.15.3; Aerospike Backup Utility Version 3.2.3; C Client Version 4.2.0;
Aerospike running on docker 2.2.0.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may help, as I noticed you are mentioning docker: https://discuss.aerospike.com/t/invalid-namespace-error/6117

(asbackup is basically failing to get the partition map, and, in that article, is about mismatched mtu).

Comment: I have not checked my settings, but the answer is probably right. As an immediate solution, I am just using go driver api to read and write json data as a way to do backup and load data.

Answer (score 0):

I would double check your namespace spelling / case sensitivity...

```
    $ asbackup --host 172.28.128.3:3000 --namespace test --directory .
2020-02-11 17:49:52 GMT [INF] [ 8221] Starting 100% backup of 172.28.128.3:3000 (namespace: test, set: [all], bins: [all], after: [none], before: [none]) to .
2020-02-11 17:49:52 GMT [INF] [ 8221] [src/main/aerospike/as_cluster.c:132][as_cluster_add_nodes_copy] Add node BB9132C60270008 172.28.128.3:3000
2020-02-11 17:49:52 GMT [INF] [ 8221] Processing 1 node(s)
2020-02-11 17:49:52 GMT [INF] [ 8221] Node ID             Objects        Replication    
2020-02-11 17:49:52 GMT [INF] [ 8221] BB9132C60270008     9              1              
2020-02-11 17:49:52 GMT [INF] [ 8221] Namespace contains 9 record(s)
2020-02-11 17:49:52 GMT [INF] [ 8221] Directory . prepared for backup
2020-02-11 17:49:52 GMT [INF] [ 8240] Starting backup for node BB9132C60270008
2020-02-11 17:49:52 GMT [INF] [ 8240] Created new backup file ./BB9132C60270008_00000.asb
2020-02-11 17:49:52 GMT [INF] [ 8240] Backing up 1 secondary index(es)
2020-02-11 17:49:52 GMT [INF] [ 8240] Backing up 4 UDF file(s)
2020-02-11 17:49:53 GMT [INF] [ 8240] Completed backup for node BB9132C60270008, records: 9, size: 8401 (~933 B/rec)
2020-02-11 17:49:53 GMT [INF] [ 8239] Backed up 9 record(s), 1 secondary index(es), 4 UDF file(s) from 1 node(s), 8401 byte(s) in total (~933 B/rec)
```

Comment: I checked it. It is "test"